# How to run Lilypond programatically from Python instead of calling the Lilypond executable to generate sheet music?

Tags: python, lilypond

Python has a library called Lilypond which can be used to generate sheet music from a text based input. The documentation shows that the normal use is to create the text file, and then from a command line execute the `lilypond` executable with the text file as the first argument, which then outputs a PDF file.

How can I instead generate the PDF of sheet music programatically from inside another python program by calling Lilypond APIs? I am not interested in making system calls from Python to the lilypond executable.

Comment: How is what you want to do different from executing it from the command line?

Comment: @martineau executing from the command line involves a manual step. By interacting with APIs I can automate this step.

Comment: In that case you'll likely only going to be able to do this if someone has written a Python extension you can install to interact with its API (LilyPond is mostly written in C++). I don't know of one (and asking for recommendations is off-topic on stackoverflow).

Comment: If you are using Python to create LilyPond scores then I would suggest you'd take a look at Abjad abjad.github.io/ which allows you to create score in a object-oriented environment.